# Where does the term firmware come from?

Tags: history, terminology, firmware

I've heard that the term **firmware** comes from it being between *hard*ware and *soft*ware. I have also heard that it refers to software that comes from the *firm* (company) that builds the hardware.

When was the term first used and what is the origin of the term?

Comment: I've never heard it being used in the second manner you described.

Comment: This should have been wiki when I asked it; my bad.

Comment: @Spencer, I am hoping that someone can find reference for that origin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware):

> The term "firmware" was coined by
>   Ascher Opler in a 1967 Datamation
>   article. Originally, it meant the
>   microcode – contents of a writable
>   control store (a specialized small
>   area of RAM memory), which defined and
>   implemented the computer's instruction
>   set....Firmware has evolved to mean
>   almost any programmable content of a
>   hardware device, not only machine code
>   for a processor, but also
>   configurations and data for
>   application-specific integrated
>   circuits (ASICs), programmable logic
>   devices, etc.

Comment: It's somewhere between hard(ware) and soft(ware) - so it's firm!

Comment: A case of 'LMWTFY' then (a variation on "LMGTFY"!)

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware#Origin_of_the_term

**Firmware**

**Origin of the term**

The term "firmware" was coined by Ascher Opler in a 1967 Datamation article.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware#Origin_of_the_term) Originally, it meant the microcode – contents of a writable control store (a specialized small area of RAM memory), which defined and implemented the computer's instruction set. The firmware could be reloaded if needed to specialize or modify the instructions that the central processing unit (CPU) could execute. As originally used, firmware was contrasted with hardware (the CPU itself) and software (normal instructions executing on a CPU). It was not composed of CPU machine instructions, but of lower-level microcode involved in the implementation of machine instructions. It existed on the boundary of hardware and software, thus the term firmware.

Later the term was broadened to include any type of microcode, whether in RAM or ROM.

Still later, the term was again broadened in popular usage to denote anything ROM-resident, including processor machine instructions for BIOS, bootstrap loaders, or specialized applications.

When it comes to the subject of updating the firmware to a new version, a typical procedure until the mid 1990s, was to replace a storage medium containing firmware, usually a socketed ROM. Nowadays, this approach is largely abandoned in presence of firmware's capability to overwrite itself in a convenient, purely electronic operation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware) to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/) will answer this, really..

Comment: @Grzegorz: Definitely yes, at least the relevant parts. Otherwise you force the reader over to another web site, where the page may have vanished or the information changed. If someone else has the same question two years from now and finds this page through google, having the answer here is much more useful than a link to where the answer used to be.

Comment: **@Graeme:** -1 for showing a user to do the very basic "search the web" he should have done bofore? wow...  This question is so really irrelevant, I tried not to be rude when answering.  This is a simple basic historical question Google answers in seconds.  but then it's your opinion.